# Как настроить переход на другие страницы в PUG?

Tags: pug

Правильно ли я понял, что при верстке на pug создается отдельный pug-файл для каждой страницы и уже потом с помощью webpack это все собирается в одно? Но я не пойму, как происходит переход на другую страницу при нажатии на ссылку? Например, есть меню ul, в котором 4 li: Главная О нас Контакты Вакансии и в ссылке на главную страницу прописан путь на определенный html файл Главная и как это делается в pug? Так же прописывается путь или нет? Может вопрос тупой, но как-то я запутался